# Excel formula (for conditional formatting) that is only looking at the cells where there is a duplicate value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, countif

I'm tracking events by participant. I'd like conditional formatting that can show me where a participant may have had multiple events happening at the same time. For example, column A has the participant identifier, column B is the event number for that participant, and C and D are the start and stop dates for the event. If my participant has 2 events, but the second event started before the first one ended I'd like to flag this event.

I have thousands of events in this list, and the majority of participants have had more than one event. If their first event ended before the second one started, no problem, I don't need to see that.

So far, I'm using a countif formula to look for duplicates, but I dont know how (if possible) to restrict the formula that shows if D is earlier than C for a specific participant's events.

Thanks in advance for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

If you can make an extra column in your data set you can do this in two steps:

Use an index-match array formula to create a column that pulls in the date of the first event

Column C is Event Date, Column A is Customer ID, Column B is event number. The following formula says, grab the event date for the matching customer ID, forced only to event #1.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(A2&"1",$A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

Then, using this new field, conditional format using a formula. I used

```
=AND(B2=2,D2>C2)
```

"If the Event Number is 2 and the 1st event date is greater than the second event date then format"

[image]